# How to properly recreate BITMAP, that was previously shared by CreateFileMapping()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Dear friends, I need your help.

I need to send .bmp file to another process (dialog box) and display it there, using MMF(Memory Mapped File)
But the problem is that image displays in reversed colors and upside down.

Here's source code:

In first application I open picture from HDD and link it to the named MMF "Gigabyte_picture"

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("123.bmp", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, "Gigabyte_picture");
```

In second application I open mapped bmp file and at the end I display m_HBitmap on the static component, using SendMessage function.

```
HANDLE hMappedFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, "Gigabyte_picture");
PBYTE pbData = (PBYTE) MapViewOfFile(hMappedFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0); 

BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = { 0 };
LONG lBmpSize = 60608; // size of the bmp file in bytes

bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 174;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 87;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = lBmpSize;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);               

UINT * pPixels = 0;    
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

HBITMAP m_HBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)& pPixels, NULL, 0);                               
SetBitmapBits(m_HBitmap, lBmpSize, pbData);
SendMessage(gStaticBox, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)m_HBitmap);
/////////////
HWND gStaticBox = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC","",
SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE | SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
10,10,380, 380, myDialog, (HMENU)-1,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: One question: SetBitmapBits copies the bits as far as I know. Do you know a way to prevent copying and to create a bitmap which directly uses the bits in pbData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pbData points to begin of bitmap data, which points to bitmap header.
Give SetBitmapBits pointer to raw data: pbData + header size + optional pallete.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I've read BMP format specification and pointed pbData to 54 bytes to the right and colors of picture became correct.

Answer (score 0):

I edited code, and it works OK now(picture colors are correct, image is NOT upside down)

```
SetBitmapBits(m_HBitmap, lBmpSize, pbFile + 54);

BITMAP bm;              
GetObject(m_HBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bm);

// this code rotate picture on 180 degrees on Y axis
HDC TempHDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(TempHDC, m_HBitmap);

::StretchBlt(TempHDC,0,0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, TempHDC,  0,  bm.bmHeight-1, bm.bmWidth,-bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY ); 
SelectObject(TempHDC,hOldBitmap2);
DeleteDC(TempHDC);

// as before
SendMessage(gStaticBox, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)m_HBitmap);
```